# Firebase invite gives error Google play service stopped

Tags: android, firebase-invites

I integrated a Firebase invite service in my app, but when I click on the send button from  the Firebase invite default email chooser screen, it gives me an error "Google play service stopped".

Please help me to resolve this error.
[Project Level Gradle configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7yrd.png) and
[App level Gradle configuration file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7k1YM.png)
Thank you.

Comment: could you share your gradle configurations? also if there is a stack trace, share it.

Comment: I added gradle file would you check and help me to resolve this error thank you.

Comment: change your highlighted sections to latest dependencies for module:     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1' and add classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' for root-level build gradle, your project build gradle

Comment: I already added "com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'" this in project level gradle configuration file.you can check project level gradle configuration file.

Comment: I changed version to  25.0.0 but still come same error Google play service stopped.

Comment: I have the same error, it is connected with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40484667/android-firebase-app-invites-securityexception-not-allowed-to-perform-system-ale

Comment: Yes still i am waiting for answer from intelligent guys .